# Sending email via intent vs without intent

Tags: android

I'm an android developer currently working on an app for the company I work for. In said application, we want to be able to export data from a Room database into a csv and send it out via email. My understanding has always been to not reinvent the wheel so when discussing this with my boss I recommended that it would be best to just use an intent to access an email application already on the device. He thinks this is "not user friendly" and "requires too many button clicks" (sidenote: He is not a programmer). He thinks we would be better off writing our own email code (Either using SMTP or HTTPS) so we can send emails with just one click.

Here is what I understand from my "research" on this topic:

**Using an Intent:**

- Generally safer so long as the user is using a secure application
- The user will feel more comfortable using an already known application
- Puts less responsibility on us if something goes wrong emailing
- Less code to support

**Writing our own email code:**

- High chance of being insecure
- User will probably not be comfortable entering their email credentials into a different app.
- Requires writing a lot more code
- Possibly faster

Obviously I'm very biased here. My opinion is simply that if you're not writing your own email application or writing something that uses a specific SMTP server (perhaps in an intranet) then there is absolutely no reason to do this.

However, I've come here because I want other peoples opinions especially if I'm lacking some knowledge and understanding here.

Comment: A third possibility is to have your Web service send the emails, assuming that there is a Web service in the mix. Ideally, `ACTION_SEND` would be the most reasonable option, but you are now relying on a semi-arbitrary third-party app, and there are lots of flaky `ACTION_SEND` implementations out there. If this is an internal app for your firm, and you know that everybody is going to be sending the message via one app (e.g., Gmail), this is less of an issue and more readily testable.

Comment: This will not be an internal app.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misinterpreted "working on an app for the company I work for". In that case, the "Writing our own email code" is a non-starter. You might get your app banned from the Play Store for asking for email credentials without adequate justification. Either use `ACTION_SEND` or have your Web service send the email (the latter mostly if it is a fixed address where the email should go).